# Is it OK to ask question concerning general game logic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question that is about the logic behind a feature I'd like to implement in my game. Although sooner or later the logic needs to be translated into code, but right now I'm more interested in the mathematics.

Is it OK to ask such a question on Stack Overflow? If so, which tags should I use? If no, what would be a better place to ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds fine for SO. There are already quite a few [physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physics) and [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) questions there, for instance, so just keep it programming-related and you'll be fine.

However, if you think you're more likely to get a good answer from game developers than from whoever might stumble across your question on SO, you could instead take it over to the new [GameDev Stack Exchange site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com). And there, your question only has to be game-related, not programming-related.